# Theme assets management in Symfony2

Tags: php, symfony

I have a Symfony2 app that must serve different themes. These themes are essentially directories containing CSS files (eventually other files and minified into a single one).

In Phalcon, I could dynamically set the asset location of my assets in the controller. In Symfony, assets are explicitly defined. My current solution is as follows, but it doesn't look great. This is the HTML of my `base.html.twig`. I have a property `theme` in my entity and I define the theme object in my controller.

Basically I'm looking for the proper way to do this in Symfony. Otherwise, I'll just do it like this.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <title>{% block title %}Welcome!{% endblock %}</title>

        <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="{{ asset('favicon.ico') }}" />
        {% if theme is defined %}
            {% for asset in theme.css %}
                <link rel="stylesheet" href="{{ asset.url }}"/>
            {% endfor %}
        {% endif %}
    </head>
    <body>
        {% block page %}
            Welcome to the default page!
        {% endblock %}
        {% block javascripts %}
            {% if theme is defined %}
                {% for asset in theme.js %}
                    <script src="{{ asset.url }}"></script>
                {% endfor %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endblock %}
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the most elegant way is to define a default theme, and put the diffrent themes into a root folder, just like this:

```
themes/
    default/
        css|js|images...
    blue/
        css|js|images...
    yellow/
        css|js|images...
```

then in Twig template engine, you can use it like this way:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="themes/{{ theme_name|default("default") }}/css/app.css"/>

<script src="themes/{{ theme_name|default("default") }}/js/app.js">
```